# RxAndroid Re-Subscribe to Observable onError and onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

My Question is probably more of the conceptual nature.
I get that by the `Observable` contract my `Observable` will not emit any more items after `onComplete` or `onError` is called.
But I'm using the RxBindings for Android and therefore it's not "my `Observable`" but the click on a `Button` that emits items.

```
fun observeForgotPasswordButton(): Disposable {
    return view.observeForgotPasswordButton()
            .flatMap {
                authService.forgotPassword(email).toObservable<Any>()
            }
            .subscribe({
                // on next
                Timber.d("fun: onNext:")
            }, { error ->
                // on error
                Timber.e(error, "fun: onError")
            }, {
                // onComplete
                Timber.d("fun: onComplete")
            })
}
```

`observeForgotPasswordButton()` returns an `Observable`

```
fun observeForgotPasswordButton(): Observable<Any> = RxView.clicks(b_forgot_password)
```

The problem is that `authService.forgotPassword(email)` is a `Completable` and it will call either `onComplete` or `onError` both of which lead to the fact that I cannot reuse the button anymore since the subscription ended.
Is there a way to circumvent this behavior?
Because in an error occurs I would like to be able to retry.
Also I would like it to be possible to send more then one password forgotten emails.

Comment: The only way for the above to get unsubscribed prematurely is for an error to happen. I think onComplete won't be called if forgotPassword is always successful. Check rxJava [error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators). Also you can use `flatMapCompletable`

Comment: I did some more digging and found a [pretty solid explanation of error handling in rx](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/). As the blog post describes it, I made the rookie mistake of throwing an exception in the `authService` instead of calling `onNext` with an error state. This is the rx-way...

Comment: @grAPPfruit using onError instead of modeling an Error state isn't a real `rookie` mistake. Even Square's Retrofit did that once.

Comment: @PhoenixWang made my day ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `retry()` and `repeat()` operators to automatically resubscribe to the original `Observable` (or `Completable`).

```
fun observeForgotPasswordButton(): Disposable {
    return view.observeForgotPasswordButton()
            .flatMap {
                authService.forgotPassword(email).toObservable<Any>()
            }
            .repeat() // automatically resubscribe on completion
            .retry()  // automatically resubscribe on error
            .subscribe({
                // on next
                Timber.d("fun: onNext:")
            }, { error ->
                // on error
                Timber.e(error, "fun: onError")
            }, {
                // onComplete
                Timber.d("fun: onComplete")
            })
}
```

Comment: With repeat the observable is going to fire up indefinitely all the initially emitted values. That means every initial user input. I don't think this is what he wants. In cases like this one, you just need to handle the error if you want to keep the observable alive.

Comment: masp is right, this is not what I want. Also I think that your answer is wrong but I'm not an expert on that so I just leave it be... @masp, what do you mean by "handling the error"? I created a test project where I `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` is my `Observable` Source. I chained that with a `.flatMapCompletable(__ -> Completable.complete())` and then subscribed with a `CompletableObserver` where I just print the method names. All I see is `onSubscribe` though. Never anything else... I don't get it.

Comment: See my comment on the question... there is the solution to the problem

Comment: @grAPPfruit an observable such as `Observable.interval` never completes unless there is an error or it gets disposed. So, you should never receive `onComplete`. Also, if you use `Completable` as a last part of your chain, you will never receive any `onNext` events either. As for the testing part, the blog you shared is the one that helped me as well. Especially the part about the masked exceptions.